# Laptop Lenovo G560 beeping

Tags: laptop, hardware-failure, diagnostic

My laptop Lenovo G560 makes these strange beeps. [I recorded it](https://filebin.net/7b9zqbtt9skzcl16/beep.3gp?t=rk2wl9uw).

It looks like it comes from this side of laptop
[image]

The beeping stops when I press <kbd>Fn+F1</kbd>

Do you know what causes it and how to fix it?

Comment: Does it boot? Or does it just beep?

Comment: @SamForbis It boots without problems. And it beeps during booting as well.

Comment: Does everything function correctly when in the OS? Keyboard? Mouse pad/tracker? USB devices?

Comment: @spikey_richie Yes, OS (Linux Lubuntu), touchpad, keyboard works fine. USB as well (I copied the recording from my mobile phone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This noise doesn't sound like a beep, but rather like a mechanical noise.

If you can, open up the case to locate the source of it by ear.
If this is the hard disk, replace it immediately.

If you can't open up the case, a repair-shop might be indicated.

Comment: I opened up the case and discovered that it was the fan. When spinning it quickly by hand makes this voice. So, I hope when I change it it will help. Or can I use some Linux utility?

Comment: This is mechanical and should be fixed. It might be simple dirt.

Comment: There is quite a lot of dust, but I can't do it with my screwdriver, so I will go to service. Thanks